# different behaviour of menu for firefox

Tags: html, css

please check the links below - the problem seems to be just with FireFox. It is the green top menu what is wrong. In chrome/ie it is in one line but in FF last 2 links are on the 2nd line - even trough I set the menu dimensions.

http://www.cotea.cz/

Any ideas what I should change or what I overlooked?

Thanks for advices

Comment: I dont know the solution to this yet, but well i observed something else weird.....eventhough the links are on the second line when page loads, when you zoom out and zoom back in, it is in one line.

Comment: i think that different font-rendering in FF causing this issue. P.S. if you add letter-spacing: -1px; to ul/list, all is in one line, but, that's not the fix, of course....

Comment: You are right so should I pick different font?

Comment: huh, don't know... try with some less exotic font... i have some font nightmares too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will fix

remove `float`

```
#main_menu a {
    border-right: 1px dotted #6F3B31;
    color: #69382E;
    font-family: "PT Sans";
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;//adjust line-height for mozilla
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
}
```

Comment: body{} add padding: 10px 0; remove height:50; #main_menu a {} remove line-height: 20px; it will fix you properly

Comment: It wont - in firefox it is still on 2 lines

Comment: check this fiddle and paste this code to your project

http://jsfiddle.net/x3gb6gcw/1/

Comment: Thanks for the efford, it fix FF but mess opera. I`ll stick to the 1st version w/o float - it works well :)